# Installing from minimal CD

Tags: xubuntu, cd, ubuntu-minimal

I'm a windows xp user and I'm new to Linux
I decided to install Xubuntu on my machine since it's quite old (512 MB ram and 2.66 GHZ P4 processor)
My machine doesn't support booting from USB so the only choise for me was installing xubuntu from minimal CD 
The problem is that I'm new to Linux ,the only OS I've ever used was windows
So in the setup process every thing went fine until the partionning process 
I want to install xubuntu next to my XP and I got only tow partitions on my 160 GB HD 
So anyone who know how to partition my HD in a way that keeps my xp and my other files ?
Thanx in advance :-)

Comment: The CD I use is Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" Minimal CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although installing from minimal will work, if you are new to linux it might be lots of touble for you. Instead, you might want to look into something called Plop Boot. Essentially, you burn a CD, then create a ubuntu usb key. You put them both in the computer, boot from CD and it will then allow you to continue booting from USB. Used it myself awhile back and works like a charm. [Plop Boot Page](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html) 
After booting, you can use Gparted to resize your partitions, then run the install.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ... It's really helped me, I want to give your answer a rank put it says that my rep is low , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think that my answer will be a little long to explain.
First, it is possible to resize the actual partition who contain Windows XP and then create a new partition to install Xubuntu on it.

You can see this nice [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Partition) to resize your windows xp partition and to create the new one for Xubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your effort sir ... I will try it as soon I return from my exam :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install ubuntu alongside xp, then your best bet is to use wubi. Just login into xp , open your cd . Click the wubi.exe and select **install inside windows**

Comment: AFAIK wubi is deprecated and no longer recommended.